# C++ Tic Tac toe game not showing X character

Tags: c++, oop

Novice programmer here. Trying to make a tic tac toe game. Everything so far works, except the character X doesn't appear. In the for loop is where I believe I have a problem but I cant seem to find anything wrong. Please help, any criticism is greatly appreciated. Good and bad. Thanks.

```
void playgame() {
    std::string input;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Go player one" << std::endl;
        getline (std::cin, input);
        if (input != " ") {
            char entered = input.c_str ()[0];

            if (entered >= '1' && entered <= '9') {
                int entered_num = entered - 0;
                int index = entered_num - 1;
                int row = index / 3;
                int col = index % 3;
                char grid_position = map[row][col];

                if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O') {
                    std::cout << "Space taken. Try again" << std::endl;
                } else {
                    map[row][col] = (char) 'X';
                    break;
                }

            } else {
                std::cout << "Only numbers 1 - 9" << std::endl;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "Have to enter something, try again" << std::endl;
        }


    }
}

void generateGrid() {
    int number = 1;

    for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
            map[x][y] = std::to_string (number).c_str ()[0];
            number += 1;
        }
    }
}

void tictacToeMap() {


    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
            std::printf (" %c ", map[x][y]);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}


TicTacToe() {
    generateGrid ();
    while (true) {
        tictacToeMap ();
        playgame ();
    }
}
};


int main() {

    TicTacToe tic;

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: As a side note: It's probably a bad idea to run your game in the class constructor function, better provide a `run()` function in your class, that can be called from `main()`.

Comment: Guess you tried to do `int entered_num = entered - '0';`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `input.c_str()[0]` should be just `input[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
            int entered_num = entered - 0;
```

Should be:

```
            int entered_num = entered - '0';
```

To convert a `'1'` into a 1, you need to subtract '0' (the character we use to represent the digit zero), not 0 (the number zero). Subtracting zero doesn't do anything.